# How can I upload multiple photos in several selections with a form input?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am trying to take and upload multiple photos on a phone.  I know how to use

`<input type="file" multiple>`

The problem is, when I press "Choose Files" it takes a picture.  However, if I click it again to add another picture, the second picture *overwrites* the first.  So, I want to be able to click the "Choose Files" button multiple times to take more photos to add to the list of photos I want to upload.

In other words, I want to evoke the camera multiple times for a single upload.

How can I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: You'd probably have to use multiple inputs or store the files with a script. I don't think you'll accomplish it with default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With default behavior you will not be able to achieve that because that is how that input works.
You can take pictures and then store them, if you are using react you can store it in a state and then do
`setImages(...images, image);` but other than that I'd suggest taking the pictures and then choosing them as files